# InvalidArgument error when calling Binding.getRange()

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

When I call the `getRange()` method on a [Binding](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/binding) object, I receive the following error:

```
code: "InvalidArgument",
errorLocation: "Binding.getRange",
message: "The argument is invalid or missing or has an incorrect format."
```

This seems nonsensical because the method does not have any parameters according to the API linked above.

Even a new project with the docs' example code for `getRange()` causes this error for me (after I've added a binding, of course):

```
Excel.run(function (ctx) { 
    var binding = ctx.workbook.bindings.getItemAt(0);
    var range = binding.getRange();
    range.load('cellCount');
    return ctx.sync().then(function() {
        console.log(range.cellCount);
    });
}).catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error: " + error);
        if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
            console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
        }
});
```

Is there some seemingly unrelated issue going on here?

I'm on Windows 10 running Office Pro Plus 2016, Version 1709 (Build 8528.2139), which supports ExcelApi 1.6.

---

*Update*

I'm also seeing this error when trying to add a binding with [bindings](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/bindingcollection)`.add()` or `.addFromNamedItem()` like so:

```
ctx.workbook.bindings.addFromNamedItem("Name", Office.CoercionType.Text, "Name");
```

yielding:

```
code: "InvalidArgument",
errorLocation: "BindingCollection.addFromNamedItem",
message: "The argument is invalid or missing or has an incorrect format."
```

My older code using the Shared API method [`addFromNamedItemAsync()`](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/bindings.bindings) successfully adds a binding without issue, however.

I'll continue experimenting in an attempt to determine if this is occurring with all Binding-related methods in the ExcelApi or with any non-Binding-related or Shared API methods.

Comment: Have you I'm not able to replicate this (literally copy and pasted your code). Are you using the production library from the CDN?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur Same result with latest office.js from nuget, CDN, and beta from CDN. I'm also getting this error from other methods (see update above). I apologize for not posting a full sample project, but I can't seem to find someplace to upload source that isn't blocked by my organization.

Comment: Have you tried replicating this in [ScriptLab](https://github.com/OfficeDev/script-lab)? Sometimes this helps narrow down what is going on.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur I was able to save a [gist of this](https://gist.github.com/bae4026e235fc373e7568efa75620baf). New snippet, added a binding and couple lines from the docs' example. Produces the error. Do it occur for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the binding the wrong way. 
First, the address should contain the sheet name as the bindings collection is on the workbook. So, it doesn't know which range you are referring to. Second, you should create binding of type Range. Lastly, using getItemAt is limiting as position can change based on delete actions. getItem with the key is a better method to get the binding object.

```
...
ctx.workbook.bindings.add("Sheet1!D3", "Range", "Binding2");
await ctx.sync();
var binding = ctx.workbook.bindings.getItem("Binding2");
var range = binding.getRange();
range.load('cellCount');
return ctx.sync().then(function () {
     console.log(range.cellCount);
});
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'd tried these things before, just not in the contrived example I provided. Why "Range" for a single cell? What would "Text" even be for?

Comment: If you need to store settings value not tied to a range, you can use Text binding. It's provided as a bridge to older API that had that option. However, for that scenario, I'd use document properties...

Comment: All I was trying to do was convert old code (that would get/set a single cell's value) written with the original shared API to the newer Excel API . All of the old code worked using a Text binding, but in the new way I'll never use Text and always use Range even to set a single cell's value?

Comment: While I still don't understand why Text bindings no longer work and must be replaced with Range bindings, switching to Range has given me a workable solution to my immediate problem. Accepting this answer.

Comment: I'm not saying the text binding doesn't work. Personally, I've not found a reason to use it. In the code, I didn't see how the text binding was added. If that is shown, I can check if there's an issue with the text binding creation or reading APIs. Thanks...